# Failed to load platform plugin in cross compiling of a Qt5.1 application for an ARM based target

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, qt5, embedded-linux, gnu-toolchain

I'm working with AM1808 based processing unit that has a Linux port on. I use Qt creator 3.0 with compiler version qt5.1.0 to build an application and install to this ARM processor as an App by cross-compiling it using the arm-2012.03 toolchain. Previously I develop the application using Qtcreator 2.4 with a qt4.7.4 compiler and it works fine in this processing unit.

The issue is faced when I cross compile the app and generate the binary and try to load into the ARM that gives me an error 
"Failed to load platform plugin ".

What is the issue with this? I run the same binary with my old compiler and I made the necessary changes required to run the same app in qt5.1.0 still it gives the error that I've never seen before. My binary is successfully generated without an error but when I run this binary, it generated this error.

Please share any solution to this...

Answer (score 0):

Qt5 come with [Qt Platform Abstraction](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpa.html). I guess, you either doesn't deploy qt-platform plugin for you embedded system or used Qt version doesn't support your platform, or...

You should probably check AM1808 forums for discussion what Qt5 version should be used and how to compile/deploy your project. Qt5.1 is quite outdated.